# how to use updateItem in dynamodb to update exist attribute and create a new one if not exist?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm writing simple programs to perform Amazon DynamoDB operations, I have two questions,

1. I want to update param "year" by using updateItem, but I got an error

> "ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: "val" (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: K6B8GC69295KUV9V7J10OCAFJJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)",

how to solve this?

2. If I want to create a new item using updateitem api, how to do that? Thanks!

   ```
   // update item
   UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withPrimaryKey("year", year, "title", title)
   .withUpdateExpression("set year = :val")
           .withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber("val", 2020))
           .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_NEW);

   try {
       System.out.println("Updating the item...");
       UpdateItemOutcome outcome = table.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
       System.out.println("UpdateItem succeeded:\n" + outcome.getItem().toJSONPretty());

   }
   catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Unable to update item: " + year + " " + title);
       System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The Syntax error you are getting is due to the first parameter of `.withNumber()`. It should a colon-prefixed token. In other words, you need to change `"val"` to `":val"`, as shown below.

change this line:

```
.withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber("val", 2020))
```

to:

```
.withValueMap(new ValueMap().withNumber(":val", 2020))
```